# Setting the detail field of a `FaultException` without object serialization

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, soap, fault

I'm trying to adapt a framework originally written for WSE to WCF. The framework sometimes throws `SoapException`s from deep in its bowels, which I would like to catch and transform into `FaultException` objects that the WCF framework will handle.

In order for the existing clients of this framework to continue working, I need the `<detail>` field of the SOAP fault message to be *exactly* what's in the `SoapException.Detail` field, but I can't find a way to accomplish this. All of the docs on MSDN are geared toward using a serialized detail object, which won't work for me. Is there any way to coerce the `SoapException` into a `FaultException` or `FaultException<T>` object that keeps the actor, code, and detail fields from the original soap exception?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, definitely, but I'm not sure -- based on your question -- whether you explored and eliminated this option for your situation.

You can use a custom WCF error handler and set the fault exception's Detail field to whatever you'd like, without any serialization or deserialization involved in the assignment process (in the HandleFault or ProvideFault methods). See http://wcfpro.wordpress.com/2010/11/18/wcf-extensions-error-handler/ , http://wcfpro.wordpress.com/2011/01/04/catching-the-real-exception/ , and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pedram/archive/2008/01/25/wcf-error-handling-and-some-best-practices.aspx to do this.